# Chart line title in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I'm working on SSRS Line Charts. In a single graph I have like 4 lines, each two is of comparisions. I woud like to add a title to each line in the chart like below. This will really help to understand the data without checking the color code of each lines from axes definitions located at the end of the chart. Please guide me how to achieve it. 
[image]

Update: Please find my requirement with the question below in Excel. I would like to do something similar in SSRS

https://superuser.com/questions/807068/how-to-display-series-name-inside-bars-of-stacked-bar-chart

Comment: How to achieve it?   I can't imagine what's stopping you from just building it with textboxes.   What part of this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Label property of the series to show the helper text conditionally to a specific x-axis value.

Click the serie you need to label, in my case the [Sum(Cancelations)] as you can see in the below screenshot.

[image]

Press `F4`, a properties window will appear. In the property window, search for Label node and expand it, you will get something like this:

[image]

In the `Label` property you have to use an expression to determine where you have to place the label, in my case I've used:

```
=IIF(Fields!Day.Value="123",
"Cancelation",
Nothing
)
```

This expression says, show the `Cancelation` label when the x-axis label is equal to `123`, if the day field (x-axis) is not `123` it shows *nothing*.

The same logic if you  want the label appearing at the beginning of your the line, in that case you have to use the first value in your x-axis.

```
=IIF(Fields!Day.Value="2",
"T-2",
Nothing
)
```

It says if Day.Value is equal to `2` then show `T-2` as the label. Otherwise show nothing.

I've created an example.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use tooltips if you are generating your report in an interactive format like MHTML. Note the tooltip appears when you pass the mouse over the line.

> Note you have to set the `Visible` property to `True` as pointed in
>   the screenshot.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you give me an example for how you got cancelation on your graph? That's what i'm looking for exactly.

Comment: Sorry to bug you! Is there any way to set it without any conditions. I just want to name the lines with the titles like Orders/ cancellation. If I Use label without conditions, it displays me the values for each data points

Comment: @Ramya, The conditional lets you place the label only in one data point. I think there is no way to place the label in one data point. Let me know if you are stuck with your conditional expression, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I think there are no conditions required in my case. By default, I need to give a title to my chart lines. With your example, Orders as to Orders line of the chart and Cancellation as to Cancellation line of the chart. I can set condtions based on day values as you suggested but sometimes there's a chance that the data points for the day not being captured which will cause the title to miss.

Comment: May be is it something to do with some properties in Default Legend of the chart?